# Ignore white spaces before and after column names in read_csv with usecols

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a CSV file like this as **data**:

```
Emp_id,   Name  ,Address  ,  Ph_no
e1,ABC,Place1,111
e2,DEF,"Place2, Place3",222
e3,GHI,"Place4, Place5",333
e4,JKL,Place6,444
```

I want the output:

```
Emp_id   Name   Address            Ph_no
e1       ABC    Place1             111
e2       DEF    Place2, Place3     222
e3       GHI    Place4, Place5     333
e4       JKL    Place6             444
```

My code for reading the csv:

```
pd.read_csv(data, skipinitialspace=True, usecols=["Emp_id", "Name", "Address", "Ph_no"])
```

The error I'm getting for the extra trailing white spaces for the column names:

```
"Usecols do not match columns, columns expected but not found: ['Name', 'Address']"
```

How can be the **extra space ignored or removed from the column names** to check with **usecols** while reading the csv?

Comment: If you want to remove trailing spaces from columns in data frames, without having to specify cols names, you can try this: `data = pd.read_table(r'file_path', sep=',')`, and then
`data.columns = [col.strip() for col in data.columns]`

Answer (score 1):

Use `.str.strip` to trim whitespace from the columns after reading the dataframe:

```
df = pd.read_csv(data, skipinitialspace=True)
df.columns = df.columns.str.strip()
```

Output:

```
>>> df
  Emp_id Name         Address  Ph_no
0     e1  ABC          Place1    111
1     e2  DEF  Place2, Place3    222
2     e3  GHI  Place4, Place5    333
3     e4  JKL          Place6    444
```

Comment: Can the column names be specified while reading the csv only @richardec?  In a large csv with many other extra columns, those columns will also be read from csv and then the specified names will be set in dataframe, so it'll take more time.

Comment: Check the answer now, @Soumee. It's dynamic.

Comment: But still, I need to specify the column names.  Just in case there are extra columns I don't want to read from csv.